# xsd unique constraint on complex type fails

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

Xsd schema

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified">
<xsd:element name="message">
<xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xsd:element ref="controlId"/>
        <xsd:element ref="date"/>
        <xsd:element ref="type"/>
        <xsd:element ref="event"/>
        <xsd:element ref="sendingFacility"/>
    </xsd:choice>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:unique name="AnswerIdUnique">
        <xsd:selector xpath="./controlId" />
      <xsd:field xpath="."/>
    </xsd:unique>
<xsd:unique name="AnswerIdUnique1">
        <xsd:selector xpath="./date" />
      <xsd:field xpath="."/>
    </xsd:unique>
<xsd:unique name="AnswerIdUnique2">
        <xsd:selector xpath="./type" />
      <xsd:field xpath="."/>
    </xsd:unique>
<xsd:unique name="AnswerIdUnique3">
        <xsd:selector xpath="./event" />
     <xsd:field xpath="."/>
    </xsd:unique>
</xsd:element>

<xsd:element name="event">
<xsd:complexType mixed="true">
    <xsd:attribute name="class" type="xsd:string" use="optional"/>
    <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" use="optional"/>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>

<xsd:element name="controlId" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element name="date" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element name="type" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element name="sendingFacility" type="xsd:string"/>
</xsd:schema>
```

xml

```
    <message>
<date></date>
<sendingFacility></sendingFacility>
<controlId></controlId>
<event>fdsf</event>
<event>fdsf</event>
</message>
```

I don't want the element event to get duplicated. If I duplicate date, it throws me appropriate error

```
 "Duplicate Unique Value [] Declared For Identity Constraint "AnswerIdUnique1" Of Element "message".."
```

but, though I have enforced unique constraint on event element, it still allows the element to get repeated. Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

Your XML doesn't have an attribute called eventId. I think you want

```
<xsd:unique name="AnswerIdUnique3">
     <xsd:selector xpath="event" />
     <xsd:field xpath="."/>
</xsd:unique>
```

Comment: @Michael Kay I edited my original question.. this doesn't enforce unique constraint as well. used this editor http://www.freeformatter.com/xml-validator-xsd.html

Comment: Sorry, but changing a question in such a way as to invalidate existing answers makes the conversation impossible to follow. So I'm pulling out of it.